# Native Code Permissions in Android App

Tags: android, c, android-manifest

I'm running some C in an Android app, but I'm getting permission denied on the following line:

```
socket_local_client("vold", ANDROID_SOCKET_NAMESPACE_RESERVED, SOCK_STREAM)
```

I assume it's something with permissions in the manifest.xml, but I can't find the right permission to add to the app.

The Java the executes the C is as follows

```
final int[] processId = new int[1];
final FileDescriptor fd = Exec.createSubprocess("/system/bin/sh", "-", null, processId);
final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fd);
String command = getFilesDir() + "/zergrush\n";
out.write(command.getBytes());
out.flush();
```

Here's my manifest (You'll notice it's a variation of z4root I'm working on, for the HTC Rezound).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.z4mod.z4root2" android:versionName="1.3.0"
android:versionCode="6">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/z4small"
    android:label="@string/z4root" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="z4root" android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:label="z4root"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:multiprocess="true"
        android:process=":three" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Phase1" android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:label="Phase1"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:multiprocess="true"
        android:process=":three" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Phase2" android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:label="Phase2"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:multiprocess="true"
        android:process=":two" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="PhaseRemove" android:theme="@style/Theme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:label="PhaseRemove"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:multiprocess="true"
        android:process=":four" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>

    <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
    <meta-data android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" android:name="ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_PUBLISHER_ID" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Comment: The only permission you should need is `INTERNET`, so something else is going on here. Do you have the <uses-permission> as a child of <manifest>. Post your whole manifest + more relevant code, it's possible that the error is marked at the wrong line (I've had that happen, weird as it was).

Comment: Are you aware to the fact that you have the internet permission twice ? I'm not sure it's related, but remove one of them.

Comment: I've updated the OP with the manifest and some more source. The line isn't marked as failing in eclipse or logcat though, I know the line through a debug statement in the C code itself.